# Get customer group from order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer, customer-group

I'm trying to get the Customer Group from the customer's order. I have the following code and I have commented the line that doesn't appear to be working;

```
<?php if($order->getCustomerId()):?>

    // Correctly gets the CustomerId from the $order
    <?php $customerId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId())?>

    // Here i'm trying to get the Customer Group but it's not being returned
    <?php $customer_group_id = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerGroupId()); ?>
    <?php $customerGroup = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($customer_group_id)->getCode() ?>

    <?php echo $customerGroup ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I wondered if someone could help me rectify this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be nearly there. Actually the 7th line is not required and messes up the script

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId())
$customerGroup = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($customer->getCustomerGroupId())->getCode();
```

Comment: Thanks @sander-mangel. For some reason it still doesn't echo out the customer group. Even though i know that the customer is a registered user assigned to a customer group.

Comment: Got it. The last line needed to be: `<?php $customerGroup = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($order->getCustomerGroupId())->getCode();?>`

Comment: Great, glad it works

Answer (score 1):

Try This;

```
<?php if ($order->getCustomerGroupId()): ?>
    <?php $customerGroup = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($order->getCustomerGroupId()); ?>
    <?php echo $customerGroup->getCustomerGroupCode(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```